# If a user write "text" more than two times a error pop up

Tags: ajax, node.js

```
if (question == "What is the market?") {
    post = "You can find it @ " + store.market + ".";
    response.sendfile("src/index.html");
}
```

I got a input text box that when a user writes Name? The computer says "My name is (me.name).

This code is in the **server.js**

But what i would like to do.. If a user write Name? like 3 times or so. it will come up a error that says You have asked me to many times or something in that way.

i tryd with for (var i=0;i < 3; ++i)
textbox = "Error"
But i cant get it to work. Im not the best programmer but im trying. Can it be done with a simple loop or do i need something more?

Comment: _“If a user write Name? like 3 times or so”_ – that is very unspecific. Do you mean he writes `name name name` into the input field in one go? Or do you mean, when the process is gone through multiple times, and he answers with `name` _each time_? In that case, you will first have to store the answers of the previous rounds somewhere, so that you can still access them to check.

Comment: I mean if a user write "What is your Name?" then ok. and then the same 2 more times. Like "What is your Name?" x3 After the third time a alert("You have asked me to many times"); or something like that. Can you give me an exampel? Would be help full.

Comment: I asked you to be more specific – and you reply in the same unspecific manner again … What __is__ “two more times”? Does he call the page where he is asked this question again, refresh it, …?

Comment: hm.. Lets see if i can specific it more. I have a index.html in that file i got a input text (search) if i write "What is your Name?" in that field the computer answer My name is Alfred. But if i ask the same question 2 more times. I'll have a alert box or something that says. You cant ask me more than once or (3 times)

Comment: Then the first thing you have to be aware of is that HTTP is a “stateless” protocol – your script has _no idea_ that the user has been asked this question before already and what he answered, unless you explicitly _make_ it know that fact somehow. This is usually done using a mechanism called “sessions”. So go read up on that please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var n=0, a=0, d=0;
if (question == "Name?") {
    if(n<3)
        answ = "I am " + me.name + ".";
    else
        answ = "You asked me that " + n + " times.";
    response.sendfile("public/index.html");
    n++;
} else if (question == "Age?") {
    if(a<3)
        answ = "I am " + me.age + " years old.";
    else
        answ = "You asked me that " + a + " times.";
    response.sendfile("public/index.html");
    a++;
} else if (question == "Do you have a name?") {
    if(d<3)
        answ = "My name is:" + me.Name";
    else
        answ = "You've asked me that " + d + " times.";
    response.sendfile("public/index.html");
    d++;
}
```

Basically you're keeping track in `a`,`n`, and `d` how many times they asked the question, and changing you're response accordingly.

Comment: Hi Jason and thanks for the replay. Im trying with your code but it dosent seems to work. It only write outs "I am me.name" but if i try to post it more than 3 times nothing happends. Any clue?

Comment: move your var declarations for a,n, & d outside of the code block serving the page. If you're not real keen on scope, make them global by making them the first line in your server file, and try moving them down 'til it doesn't work. Then move them up to the last working line.

Comment: Thanks alot Jason. I got it now :)